# Move selected document to subsite document library

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, move, cross-site

I planning to use Plumsail workflow action pack OR sharepoint REST API to do this action.

This is how the workflow should run:
1. user upload t1.txt
2. user upload t2.txt and superseded t1.txt.
3. the t1.txt should move to selected subsite document library.

Q: How should I move the t1.txt to subsite document library? I tried to use Copy Document action from Plumsail, but it only copy the current item.

I using sharepoint designer 2013, there is no coding for me.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All "moves" in SharePoint are essentially a two step copy and delete operation. You can mimic the same by just adding a Delete Document action after a successful Copy action.